# Creating Gatling ScenarioBuilder using multiple ChainBuilders groups

Tags: java, gatling

In gatling, How do I create scenarioBuilder by iterating on the `groupBuilderMap`?

I attempted with the  below code , however I see only the first chainBuilder group gets executed . The session gets invalidated for the subsequent chain builder groups, and the session attributes does not get resolved.

```
protected ScenarioBuilder createScenario(GatlingScenario scenario) {
        Map<String, ChainBuilder[]> groupBuilderMap = scenario.getGroupChainBuilderMap();

        this.scenarioBuilder = scenario(this.gatlingScenario.getScenarioName())
                .exec(session -> session.
                        setAll(Map.of("timeStamp", nlocalDateTime, "baseUrl", this.baseUrl)));

        groupBuilderMap.forEach((groupName, chainBuilders) -> {
            this.scenarioBuilder = this.scenarioBuilder
                    .group(groupName)
                    .on(exec(chainBuilders));
        });
        return this.scenarioBuilder;
    }

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class GatlingScenario {
    private String scenarioName;
    private Map<String ,ChainBuilder[]> groupBuilderMap;
}
```

That's how I'm initializing the ChainBuilder . Only the loginChainBuilder gets executed. The session gets invalidated for the `addItemChainbuilder` as the session attributes does not get resolved.

How do I maintain the session from loginChainBuilder to addItemChainBuilder. ?

```
ChainBuilder[] loginChainBuilder = new ChainBuilder[]{
                login.doLogin,
                lPlan.doAdminLoginMain,
                lmsUser.doGetUserMetaData
        };

  ChainBuilder[] addItemChainbuilder = new ChainBuilder[]{
                userItem.doGetItem,
                userItem.doGetItemSearch,
                userItem.doAllItemSearch,
                userItem.getDoGetItemById,
                userItem.doAssignItemToUser
        };

  Map<String,ChainBuilder[]> gpNameChainBuilderMap = Stream.of(
                Map.entry("Login Group",loginChainBuilder),
                Map.entry("AddItemGroup",addItemChainbuilder)
        ).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I managed to get this working like so :

```
 protected ScenarioBuilder createScenario(GatlingScenario scenario) {

        List<ChainBuilder> chainBuildersList = new ArrayList<>();

        LinkedHashMap<String,List<ChainBuilder>> groupChainMap = 
                             scenario.getGroupChainBuilderMap();

        groupChainMap.forEach((groupName,groupChainList) -> {
            chainBuildersList.add(
               exec(group(groupName).on(exec((groupChainList)))));
        });

        return scenario(scenario.getScenarioName())
                .exec(session -> session.setAll(Map.of(
                       "timeStamp", nlocalDateTime, "baseUrl", this.baseUrl)))
                .exec(chainBuildersList);

    }

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class GatlingScenario {
    private String scenarioName;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, List<ChainBuilder>> groupChainBuilderMap;
}

// ChainBuilders are like :

   List<ChainBuilder> loginChainList = List.of(LLogin.doLogin,
                LPlan.doAdminLoginMain);

   List<ChainBuilder> getUserChainList = 
             List.of(LmsUser.doGetUserMetaData,
                LUser.doGetUserInitSearchEndPoint,
                LUser.doSearchAllUsers);
```